# #define SIZEOF Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an Xcode project, and in my UIView.h I have this like of code:

```
#define FINGER_SIZE 20
```

Tell me please, how can I change the value of FINGER_SIZE, from another UIView.

I have SecondView, and UIButton. I need something like:

```
    -(IBAction)changeSize
{

//Change FINGER_SIZE from 20 to 50

}
```

The "changeSize" action I have in my SecondView, and #define FINGER_SIZE 20, I have in UIView.h

Thank you.

Comment: That's not how macros work. They are set at compile time and you can't adjust them at run time. If you need to adjust them at run time use a variable.

Comment: This have been identified in the pre-compiled, can not be changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#define` preprocessor construct does not define a variable, it defines a constant. It is not possible to change the value of `FINGER_SIZE`, because it does not exist by the time the Objective C compiler starts looking at your code: it's replaced by `20` by then.

What you are looking for is a *global variable*. Declare it in the header like this

```
extern NSUInteger FINGER_SIZE;
```

and then define it in a `.m` file like this:

```
NSUInteger FINGER_SIZE = 20;
```

Now you have an assignable variable that you can change freely from any method that sees the declaration.